# Java Stream API: IntStream to Map

Tags: java, compiler-errors, java-stream, functional-interface

The task is to generate a Map, with keys, represented as integers in the range from 0 to 10, and values, represented as a string value, contcatenated with key-value.

For example,`{ key = 1, value = "client_1"; key = 2, value = "client_2" .... }`

I tried to do this as shown below:

```
Map<Integer, String> clients = IntStream.range(1, 10).collect(Collectors.toMap(Function.identity(), new Function<Integer, String>() {
        @Override
        public String apply(Integer integer) {
            return new StringBuilder().append("client_").append(integer).toString();
        }
    }));
```

And in lambda:

```
 Map<Integer, String> clients = IntStream.range(1, 10).collect(Collectors.toMap(Function.identity(),
            integer -> new StringBuilder().append("client_").append(integer).toString()));
```

But IDEA marks this with error and informs, that **required** type is Supplier<R  and **provided**:
Collector<Integer,capture of ?,java.util.Map<java.lang.Object,java.lang.String>>

Collectors.toMap has the following signature:

```
  toMap(Function<? super T, ? extends K> keyMapper,
        Function<? super T, ? extends U> valueMapper)
```

I passed into this method arguments with Function-type. Why the Supplier is required?

Comment: Method `IntStream#collect` differs from `Stream#collect` - it doesn't accept `Collector` argument and doesn't return `Map` as a result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An `IntStream` produces a stream of `int`s, not `java.lang.Integer`s, and hence the compiler error. One solution is to box the steam to convert them to `Integer`s:

```java
Map<Integer, String> clients = 
    IntStream.range(1, 10).
             .boxed() // Here!
             .collect(
                  Collectors.toMap(Function.identity(),
                  i-> new StringBuilder().append("client_").append(i).toString()));
```

Comment: Also the string builder is totally useless here. `new StringBuilder().append("client_").append(i).toString()` -> `"client_" + i`

Comment: @Michael true 'dat. I tried sticking to the OP's code as closely as possible as to not not lose focus on the answer, but you are of course correct.